# Issue with drawing to backbuffer in Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paint

I want to draw to a backbuffer which will then display on a JPanel, but I can't get my drawings to apply and it will only display as a completely black screen.

Any ideas?

My current code:

```
public class Game extends JPanel {

    int screenWidth = 1280;
    int screenHeight = 720;
    BufferedImage backbuffer;
    Graphics2D g2d;
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    Polys polygon = new Polys();

    public void init() {
        backbuffer = new BufferedImage(screenWidth, screenHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        g2d = backbuffer.createGraphics();
    }

    public void update(Graphics g) {
        g2d.setColor(Color.PINK);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        drawStuff();
        paint(g);
    }

    public void drawStuff() {
        g2d.setTransform(at);
        g2d.translate(10, 10);
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawPolygon(polygon.getPoly());
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(backbuffer, 0, 0, this);
    }

    Game() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidth, screenHeight));
        init();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Game());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any ideas? == yes there are three - 1. override paintComponent instead of paint, 2. inside custom painting 1st code line should be super.paint/paintComponent, 3. update () should be translated to the arrays of Object painted inside paintComponent, initialized by repaint()

Comment: A repaint() was needed. Got it to work with a Canvas but not with JPanel (with paintComponent) for some reason. update() does not get called with paintComponent maybe?

Comment: you called protected method update(Graphics g) directly, all custom painting should be done in paintComponent (all Object should be prepared before repaint() is called), for more info to read Oracle tutorial Graphics2d (Custom Painting too for working code examples)

Answer (score 1):

> Got it to work with a Canvas but not with JPanel (with paintComponent) for some reason. update() does not get called with paintComponent maybe?

Don't override the update() method. That is old AWT code and is not done in Swing. The painting to the BufferedImage can just be done in your constructor when you create the BufferedImage. But in general you would only use a BufferedImage when you image is static.

In your case I would suggest you don't need a BufferedImage. Just do all the custom painting in the `paintComponent(...)` method.